# Why do dict and lru_cache treat keys that all hash to 0 differently?

Tags: python, dictionary, hash

Since the values: `0`, `0.0`, `0j`, `False`, and `""` (empty string) all have a hash value of `0` I expected that using each of these values as a `dict` key would result in a `dict` with only one item. However, for some reason, the empty string key is treated differently resulting in a `dict` with two items.

Furthermore if you pass the same keys to a function cached with the `@lru_cache( ... )` decorator, the resulting cache treats `0`, `0.0`, and empty string differently, even though they have the same hash value and type checking is configured as `False` in the cache.

Why is empty string treated as a different key from a numeric 0 in both cases? And why is 0 treated as a different key from 0.0, and from empty string in the `lru_cache` case?

```py
keys = [0, 0.0, 0j, False, ""]
values = "abcde"

print("\nthe hash value of each key IS 0 is", 
      all(hash(k) is 0 for k in keys))

mydict = dict(zip(keys, values))
print("\nHowever a dict treats empty string differently:")
print(mydict)


from functools import lru_cache

@lru_cache(maxsize=100, typed=False)
def compute(x):
    print("lru_cache says: haven't", x, "before")

print("\nwhereas lru_cache, even with typing turned off,")
print("treats 0, 0.0, and empty string differently:\n")
for k in keys:
    compute(k)
```

the output shows:

```
the hash value of each key IS 0 is True

However a dict treats empty string differently:
{0: 'd', '': 'e'}

whereas lru_cache, even with typing turned off,
treats 0, 0.0, and empty string differently:

lru_cache says: haven't 0 before
lru_cache says: haven't 0.0 before
lru_cache says: haven't  before
```

Comment: I would have to look but I think lru_cache uses `(type(x), x)` as its dictionary key rather than `x`.

Comment: well if I set typed=True then lru_cache does appear to use the key you suggest as it will then differentiate between the various numeric forms of 0 but I was using lru_cache with typed=False which the docs say should make it not differential between types yet it still considers 0 and 0.0 to be different but 0 and False to be the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dictionaries don't only use the hash to determine if elements are distinct, they are also checked for equality.

Duplicate elements are elements which are equal, as determined by `__eq__`. The behavior you see can be explained by the fact that `0 == ""` returns `False`.

```
>>> 0 == 0.0
True
>>> 0 == 0j
True
>>> 0 == False
True
>>> 0 == ""
False
```